# Can't find UIWebView in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm trying to show webview in a table cell.
The error **Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional** pops up at **"let webView = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIWebView"**. The tag of webView is 12(cross checked it many times). dateLabel and captionLabel are working fine.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : UITableViewCell!
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCellPost", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let dateLabel = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel
    let captionLabel = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UILabel
    let webView = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIWebView
    dateLabel.text = "8/18/2015"
    captionLabel.text = "Dummy text."
    webView.loadRequest(getRequest())
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck "**Use size classes**" under file inspector in Utility tab. It is working fine now. For some reason ViewWithTag returns nil when size classes is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a custom cell. You do not need to access it's subview with tag. You can directly access them as properties.

```
    if let customCellObject = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCellPost", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell  {
        customCellObject.dateLabel?.text = "8/18/2015"
        customCellObject.captionLabel?.text = "Dummy text."
        customCellObject.webView?.loadRequest(getRequest())
        return customCellObject
    }
```

Of course outside the if block you need to handle the case if you custom cell is not dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateLabel: UILabel = UILabel() 
let captionLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
let webView : UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: cell.frame) 

dateLabel.text = "8/18/2015"
captionLabel.text = "Dummy text."
webView.loadRequest(getRequest())
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
[cell.addSubview(webView)];
```

//you should have viewWithTag 10 and 11.

```
func getRequest()-> NSURLRequest!{
let urlPath: String = "http://www.google.com"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
return request1
}
```

Comment: dateLabel should have tag 10, captionLabel  tag 11 and webView tag 12

Comment: if you set these tag and your cell style should to set custom then it will work . I checked it.